# How to deploy container to local kubernetes environment such as kind?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, localhost, registry, kind

I built a docker image on local. Its name is myapp.

Deploy it as `myjob.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: myapp
spec:
  schedule: "*/2 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: myapp
              image: myapp
```

Use [kind](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/) as a local k8s cluster environment. Load this image:

```
kind load docker-image myapp
```

Deploy app:

```
kubectl apply -f myjob.yaml
```

Confirm the pods' log, it can find the image `myapp`.

Is it necessary to create a container register on local to serve images?

Comment: What's the error you're getting?  There's [a note in the kind documentation](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/quick-start/#loading-an-image-into-your-cluster) that specifying `image: myapp` with an implicit `...:latest` tag will cause the cluster to try to pull the image again, so you either need a per-build tag (preferred) or to explicitly specify `imagePullPolicy: Never`.

Comment: @DavidMaze You are right. Can you write it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Providing an answer based on @David Maze comment.

There's [a note in the kind documentation](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/quick-start/#loading-an-image-into-your-cluster) that specifying `image: myapp` with an implicit `...:latest` tag will cause the cluster to try to pull the image again, so you either need a per-build tag (preferred) or to explicitly specify `imagePullPolicy: Never`

[image]